# Wi-Fi triangulation calculation android

Tags: java, android, wifi, triangulation

I can't find any correct information on using triangulations for finding my position if I have 3 Wi-Fi points (or more)
I have 3 Wi-Fi  access points. I have them  lat and long  (lat1,long1, lat2,long2, lat3, long 3 ) 
In app I'm scanning this points  and trying to calculate distance using this formula :

```
public double calculateDistance(double signal, double freq) {
    double exp = (27.55 - (20 * Math.log10(freq)) + Math.abs(signal)) / 20.0;
    return Math.pow(10.0, exp);
}
```

Based on frequency (mHz) and signal strength. Result of distance strange as it need, because signal not good. 
When I have 3 items of distance (example 10meters , 100 meters and 70 meters) and also I have lat/long of Wi-Fi  acces points - HOW I can calculate my position ? Please, can any one tell me .  To much information on the internet - but there are only words. Lat/Long - need convert to normal coordinates ? (x,y) Ff yes - how about distance in meters? Ff some one points have coords 50,50 and distance = 70 metters. Any helpful information about it ?

Comment: Do you understand the mathematics involved? If you have the positions of the access points and the distance to them, could you do the calculations by hand?

Comment: no , because distance in metters. access point int lat/long

Comment: Look at packages like [GeoTransform](http://www.ai.sri.com/geotransform/) or [jcoord](http://www.jstott.me.uk/jcoord/). You can transform your [GDC Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) into [GCC / ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) cooridinates. Hopefully you know which ellipsoid you're using.